# C# List variable are linked like pointer

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core

Can anybody explain why  if I change clone variable list..lista variable is also updated like pointer in C?
*Not using static variables..just using aspcore web api basic template

```
 var rng = new Random();
 List<WeatherForecast> lista = new List<WeatherForecast>();
 List<WeatherForecast> clone = new List<WeatherForecast>();
 lista = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
 {
      Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
      TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
      Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
 }).ToList();
 clone = lista;
 clone[0].Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);
 return lista;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types

Comment: To work as you probably expect, `clone = lista;` would have to be `clone = lista.ToList();`. This would create a real copy of the __data__, not just of the variable __reference__.

Comment: Let's read your code. You declare and initialize two list variables and initialize them to two newly created lists. Then you take one of those variables and assign a whole new list to it (so the original list it referred to is eligible for garbage collection). Then you assign that new list to the other list variable, so that both variables now refer to the same list. The. You mutate that list (that both variables refer to) and return it. The answer to your question is that Lists are reference types. Both variables refer to the same list after `clone = lista;` is executed

Answer (score 4):

Because you say:

```
clone = lista;
```

This means that your `clone` and your `lista` now both refer to the same single list object in memory.

Pictorially, you could conceive it looks like this (sorry for the crudeness of the sketch; fingersize:screensize ratio on my cell makes it hard to be neat)

[image]

There was no point making `lista` or `clone` as `new` on the first place, because you subsequently threw both those new lists away and attached both your references to the third list object created by `ToList` on the `Select`

It's probably also worth pointing out that TaW's comment may not be correct in the context of your code. Calling

```
clone = lista.ToList();
```

will clone the *list* itself but it will not clone the WeatherForecast objects inside the list. Cloning the list will mean that you end up with two separate list objects in memory but each of `lista[0]` and `clone[0]` will refer to the same WeatherForecast object, so if you alter a property of that weather forecast such as the date, then read it back via either list, you're seeing the same weather forecast - it'll look like either list will see the change

Pictorially it could conceivably be arranged in memory like:

[image]

Because you've now made *different lists* you could for example:

```
lista.Insert(0, new WeatherForecast(...));
```

And now `lista[0]` and `clone[0]` are different WeatherForecast objects , but `lista[1]` and `clone[0]` refer to the same WeatherForecast because inserting the new WeatherForecast in `lista[0]` will cause what was in 0 to bump along to index 1 . You can manipulate the lists independently, but they may still share some objects

[image]

These scenarios are usually a bit confusing so feel free to add a comment if there's anything unclear and we can explain further

Comment: Interesting.. this is not happening with just a single var.. just with List

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's the exact code? It may be the single var you're referring to is a value type

Comment: @elidexter Read about the difference between reference types (class) and value types (struct)

Comment: @elidexter - You would need to show us what code you're using with a single `var` and I think we could help clear up any misconceptions.

Comment: The word 'clone' is rather ambiguous. My comment showd how to create a copy, albeit a __shallow__ one. There is no easy way to create a truly/fully deep copy unless you have an object type with its own 'deepcopy' function. - But yes, his example of `clone[0].Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);` will indeed not work there, as he would indeed need __new__ instances of each element..